# Is putExtra the only way of passing data to a new Activity?

Tags: java, android

I have created a SettingsActivity for my app.  In this `Activity` I am using the `SharedPreferences` class to do handle the user editable preferences.

While setting up the `SharedPreferences`, I have to load them in the `onCreate` of my main activity and then again in the SettingsActivity.  The probably was that both calls to the `getXXXX()` methods require defaults and I figured that it would not be good to hard-code the default values into both places because I would imagine it would be problematic in the future if I ever changed them.

Which is the best/most popular (or accepted standard) of doing this?

- Create a global variables class in which I import into each activity and define my default constants in there?
- Use `putExtra` and `getExtra` to pass the data from the main activity to the settings activity?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I think that your first option sounds like a good solution. Using `public static final` variables in a centralized class is a Java idiom for providing constant values which can be shared by other classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Squonk has a good answer, but if you're looking for an alternative, consider creating a `Settings` class with all of your settings as members. It could have a static method like `loadFromPreferences(Context)` that would return a `Settings` object constructed from `SharedPreferences`, using whatever defaults you need. It could also have a `saveSettings(Context)` method to save your edits. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, in this situation, I'd put the default values in a resource file. In that way there's no need to use a global variables class or a helper class. Android resources already do that for you.

See:

[Providing resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

[More resource types](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html)

Comment: This seems like an unbelievably simple solution.  I'll try it.

Comment: @JimThornton : Indeed. And if the data type is a `String` (for example) you can even use localization by creating different `/res/values-xx` directories (where xx is the country/language code) and the OS will automatically pick the right one.

Comment: If your settings will ever need default value calculated in code, then problem will be back again.

Comment: @squonk : I seem to have run into a problem.  I read the link you gave me but it seems as though it is types Bool, Color, ID, Dimensions, Integer, Integer Array and Typed Array.  Not sure how I can make this work.  I have 5 values that need to be saved 2xLong, 1xBoolean, 2xString & 1 Integer.

Comment: @marcin_j : what do you mean by the problem will be back.

Comment: @JimThornton : Other than the fact `Long` isn't a specific type mentioned in the documentation, remember it is just an `Integer` type. I also added a link to my original answer pointing to the use of `String` in resource files. One thing to understand is a resource file can have a mixture of types - ultimately they will be built in to the auto-generated `R.java` class and will be referenced by name. Just make sure they all have unique names.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a class with static values why dont you extend the Application class which will always live when the application's process lives. you can keep shared methods and variables in it

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend opening the SharedPreference in the onCreate of both activities. Every time I've tried to use global variables, the values disappear in a way that's difficult to detect and fix. Activities are destroyed when they are closed. Services can be removed from memory at any time. The application context will be destroyed if your services are sleeping and don't have activities in memory.

That being said, putting a variable in the application context is probably the best place. Create a class that extends Application and set AndroidManifest.xml to use this. Just don't expect the value to be there if you try to use it from services or broadcast receivers.

Also, unless you're having problems with the activities loading too slowly, you're better off spending time on features than optimization.

Comment: I currently have the SharedPreferences in the onCreate of both activities.  However, this seems to be what is creating my problem.  I thought, logically, that hard-coding the default values into each getXXXX() method is going to be problematic down the road so I figured there has to be a betther way.  This is less about optimizing my code and more about learning the "correct" or "accepted" way of doing things.  There are a lot of ways that you can get things to work, but since I'm just learning, I figure it is better to learn how to do it efficiently from the beginning.

Answer (score -2):

You can declare objects as `public static` and reference them from another class.  
ActivityA:

```
public static int testIntegerA = 42;

Intent intentInteger = new Intent(getActivityContext(), ActivityB.class);
intentInteger.putExtra("INTENT_EXTRA", testIntegerA);
startActivity(intentInteger);
```

ActivityB:

```
public static int intentInt, staticInt;

staticInt = ActivityA.testIntegerA;
intentInt = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("INTENT_EXTRA");
```

Now both `intentInt` and `staticInt` equal 42;

Comment: Not a good design model. There are no reasons I can think of where an Android `Activity` class needs to be used to maintain global variables.

Comment: If you have an app with linear navigation, and you have a variable that is used in each, say the contents of an email, where each activity changes the message before passing it to the next activity, which changes it further, this method words fine.

Comment: How do you define "linear navigation"? Also, the Android design is to allow external apps to start components of any 3rd-party app if they register an `<intent-filter>` for a particular purpose. Suppose I create an app which includes a PDF viewer and register `ACTION_VIEW` for the PDF mime-type. Your app then needs to view a PDF file and my `Activity` starts but it needs to access `static` fields of another `Activity` in my app. Why should my PDF viewer `Activity` need to access `static` members of another `Activity` in order to fulfil the `<intent-filter>` contract for your app?

Comment: Linear is a path of ActivityA -> ActivityB -> ActivityC -> ActivityD and is described here as [this](http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/descendant-lateral.html) under descendent navigation.

Comment: But there are plenty of Android apps which don't run in that fashion. I have about 20 `Activity` based classes in my current app and the user can go to various ones either using a dashboard, options menu, preference screen, fired by a tapping on a `Notification`. There's no single point of entry except my `LAUNCHER` `Activity` - all other `Activity` classes can be started from different parts of my app or by external means. That's kind of what OO design is about.